# Stopping user input i.e. freezing game to display next level and such

Tags: android, touch

What is the right way to stop user input when promoting the game to next level or game over f.i.?

I @override the onTouchEvent in a class called GameManager. Should I check for a public boolean there and set it to false when level is completed, for instance? Or is there a better, cleaner way?

Comment: Even I was about to suggest the same way. I think this should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show your own custom dialog to inform the user about his win. As dialog is visible, user will not be able to touch anywhere else other than dialog. But, in that case, the dialog is clickable and you can take input from it. If user says OK, simply resume your game.

Or if you don't want to show any dialog or anything like that, then just override `onTouch()` as you said and set a global boolean value as you said.